# Parent form sometimes does not close (Only in Windows 10)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, desktop-application

My main form is frmInvoice. This sub is located inside frmInvoice.

This is one of the Subs that sometimes causes frmDark to not close. frmLookup does not display when this happens. frmDark just stays there covering frmInvoice. It's like it doesn't reach the call to frm.ShowDialog(frmDark), cause when I press the lookup key, it displays the frmLookup, but upon closing frmLookup, frmDark is still there.

No exception is being raised.

Note that this only happens in Windows 10. In Windows 8/7, this never happened. What am I missing?

This happens at different times. Sometimes I could press the lookup key for 20 times and it will display fine. Sometimes, after 1 press of the lookup key and this happens.

```
Private Sub ItemLookup()
    Try
        Using frmDark As New Form
            With frmDark
                .ShowInTaskbar = False
                .Icon = Me.Icon
                .FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
                .BackColor = Color.Black
                .Opacity = 0.95
                .WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
                .Show(Me)
                Using frm As New frmLookup
                    With frm
                        .Icon = Me.Icon
                        .ShowDialog(frmDark)
                        frmDark.Close()
                        If .DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                            ' Do stuff here
                        End If
                    End With
                End Using
            End With
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrMsg(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

UPDATE: I'm using .Net Framework 4.8

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us the `InitialiseComponent()` code? Or a small [mcve]? You're saying there is a breaking change!

Comment: The best way would be to start a new project and try to work on a [repro] as Jeremy suggested. If you then [edit] the question and post that [repro], chances are, someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rearranging the code like so:

```vb
Dim lookupResult As DialogResult

Using frmDark As New Form With {.ShowInTaskbar = False,
                                .Icon = Me.Icon,
                                ...}
    frmDark.Show(Me)

    Using frm As New frmLookup With {.Icon = Me.Icon}
        lookupResult = frm.ShowDialog(frmDark)
    End Using
End Using

If lookupResult = DialogResult.OK Then
    '...
End If
```

Because that code exits the `Using` block that created `frmDark`, there should be no way that it can't close.

Also, instead of using a vanilla `Form` and configuring it on demand, I would suggest that you create a dedicated form type to use as the overlay in that scenario. You can then get rid of all the property assignments.

Having a dedicated overlay form would also allow you to reconfigure things significantly and, in my opinion, better. The overlay form could have a property of type `Form`. You main form could then create a `frmLookup` instance and assign it to that property, than call `ShowDialog` on the overlay form. In the `Shown` event handler of the overlay form, it could then call `ShowDialog` on the form in that property. When that call returns, it could assign the result to its own `DialogResult` property and close itself. The main form would then just get the result from calling `ShowDialog` on the overlay. That might look like this:

```vb
Public Class OverlayForm

    Public Property DialogueForm As Form

    Private Sub OverlayForm_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        DialogResult = DialogueForm.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

End Class
```

and this:

```vb
Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using dialogue As New DialogueForm,
              overlay As New OverlayForm With {.DialogueForm = dialogue}
            If overlay.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                MessageBox.Show("OK")
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```